# how to access to many webpages in casperjs

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

I'm a beginner in casperjs, I'm tryin to automatically access to a website and scrape some information, I start the url and then store  some links in a table called "links" and then I try to click on the first element(links[0]) in that table and finally test if the link that has the id("ctl0_CONTENU_PAGE_resultSearch_PagerTop_ctl2")exists.

the problem is, i can't get any output, i guess it's because the program can't access to the link(links[0]) in the first place, that's why it can't find the id i'm looking for.
this is the code I wrote.

```
 var url=''; //first link
 var casper = require('casper').create();
 var links;
 var lien;// second link
 function getLinks() {
 var links = document.querySelectorAll('td a');
 return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function (e) {
  return e.getAttribute('href')
 });
 }
 casper.start(url);
 casper.then(function () {
 links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
 });

 casper.then(function () {
 lien = links[0];
 });
 casper.thenOpen(lien , function(){
 if (this.exists('a[id="ctl0_CONTENU_PAGE_resultSearch_PagerTop_ctl2"]')) {
 this.echo('the heading exists');
 }
 else {console.log('does not exist');
 }
    });
 casper.run(function () {
 this.exit();
 });`
```

[this is the link I'm trying the find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kor7.png)

Note that the versions o casperjs I'm using is 1.1.4

[this is what shows the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCkO4.png)

Comment: Please provide in your question versions of casperjs and phanomjs you are using and preferably the whole output you have in your console.

Comment: I'have added them to the question.

Comment: That means that code breaks before opening the page, on this line

`casper.start(url);`

I will try to run it in few hours and get back to you

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll be waiting for your answer

Comment: But I need to know what kind of browser are you using phantomjs or slimerjs?

Comment: I'm using phantomjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for this to work you need to wrap it in test suite. At least that is how I did it. I am not up to date with casper and I don't know if anything changed in past year, but formerly issue was that you could not start casper without test suite in v1.

Please start following code in your terminal with following command

`casperjs test filename.js`

in your filename.js put the following code

```
var url = 'https://www.marchespublics.gov.ma/pmmp/';
var url2 = 'https://www.marchespublics.gov.ma/index.php5?page=entreprise.EntrepriseAdvancedSearch&AllCons&EnCours&domaineActivite=1.15';

casper.test.begin('Scraping start', 3, function(test) {
    casper.start(url, function() {
        this.test.pass('Opened 1st page');
    })
    .thenOpen(url2, function(){
        this.test.pass('Opened 2nd page')
    })
    .then(function() {
        if (this.exists('a[id="ctl0_CONTENU_PAGE_resultSearch_PagerTop_ctl2"]')) {
            this.test.pass('the heading exists');
        } else {
            this.test.fail('Does not exist');
        }
    })
    .run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

for more details from casperjs in execution of the script try running it with additional parameters like this

`casperjs test filename.js --verbose --log-level=debug`

Hope that helps

EDIT 1:

This works as well without test suite just call this code

`casperjs filename.js`

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var url = 'https://www.marchespublics.gov.ma/index.php5?page=entreprise.EntrepriseAdvancedSearch&AllCons&EnCours&domaineActivite=1.15';

casper
    .start(url, function() {
        this.echo('Opened page')
    })
    .then(function() {
        if (this.exists('a[id="ctl0_CONTENU_PAGE_resultSearch_PagerTop_ctl2"]')) {
            this.echo('the heading exists');
        } else {
            this.echo('Does not exist');
        }
    })
    .run();
```

Comment: I updated my answer, since now had more time to try it out, so feel free to try new snippet